# Python OPCUA, modbus communication code gets a RuntimeError after 3 hours of running

Tags: python, asynchronous, opc-ua, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I've got this python program that handles communication between a PLC using OPCUA, some mass flow controllers using Modbus TCP and an Arduino using Serial. The program is supposed to run continuously and it does so for 3 hours with no trouble as my PLC is controlling another system but after this I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 230, in open_secure_channel
    raise RuntimeError('Two Open Secure Channel requests can not happen too close to each other. ' 'The response must be processed and returned before the next request can be sent.')
RuntimeError: Two Open Secure Channel requests can not happen too close to each other. The response must be processed and returned before the next request can be sent.
ERROR:asyncua.client.client:Error in watchdog loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 551, in _monitor_server_loop
    _ = await self.nodes.server_state.read_value()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 207, in read_value   
    result = await self.read_data_value()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 220, in read_data_value
    return await self.read_attribute(ua.AttributeIds.Value, None, raise_on_bad_status)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 342, in read_attribute
    result = await self.session.read(params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 404, in read    
    data = await self.protocol.send_request(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 165, in send_request
    await self.pre_request_hook()
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 534, in check_connection
    await self._renew_channel_task
RuntimeError: Two Open Secure Channel requests can not happen too close to each other. The response must be processed and returned before the next request can be sent.
ERROR:asyncua.client.client:Error in watchdog loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 551, in _monitor_server_loop
    _ = await self.nodes.server_state.read_value()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 207, in read_value   
    result = await self.read_data_value()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 220, in read_data_value
    return await self.read_attribute(ua.AttributeIds.Value, None, raise_on_bad_status)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 342, in read_attribute
    result = await self.session.read(params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 404, in read    
    data = await self.protocol.send_request(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 165, in send_request
    await self.pre_request_hook()
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 534, in check_connection
    await self._renew_channel_task
RuntimeError: Two Open Secure Channel requests can not happen too close to each other. The response must be processed and returned before the next request can be sent.
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<Client._monitor_server_loop() done, defined at C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py:542> exception=RuntimeError('Two Open Secure Channel requests can not happen too close to each other. The response must be processed and returned before the next request can be sent.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 551, in _monitor_server_loop
    _ = await self.nodes.server_state.read_value()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 207, in read_value   
    result = await self.read_data_value()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 220, in read_data_value
    return await self.read_attribute(ua.AttributeIds.Value, None, raise_on_bad_status)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\common\node.py", line 342, in read_attribute
    result = await self.session.read(params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 404, in read    
    data = await self.protocol.send_request(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\ua_client.py", line 165, in send_request
    await self.pre_request_hook()
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 534, in check_connection
    await self._renew_channel_task
RuntimeError: Two Open Secure Channel requests can not happen too close to each other. The response must be processed and returned before the next request can be sent.
INFO:asyncua.client.client:disconnect
INFO:asyncua.client.ua_client.UaClient:close_session
INFO:asyncua.client.ua_client.UASocketProtocol:close_secure_channel
INFO:asyncua.client.ua_client.UASocketProtocol:Request to close socket received
INFO:asyncua.client.ua_client.UASocketProtocol:Socket has closed connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Automation_test.py", line 339, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\labuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 685, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\labuser\Documents\Automation\Lib\site-packages\asyncua\client\client.py", line 700, in close_session
    await self._renew_channel_task
RuntimeError: Two Open Secure Channel requests can not happen too close to each other. The response must be processed and returned before the next request can be sent.
```

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import serial
from asyncua import Client, ua
from pymodbus.client import AsyncModbusTcpClient
from struct import pack, unpack
import pandas as pd
# Initialize DataFrame to store recorded variables
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamp', 'Variable', 'Value'])
# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Define the serial port and baud rate
arduino = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600) 
asyncio.sleep(2)
 
async def record_variables(variable, value):
    dosing_time = pd.Timestamp.now()
    global df
    new_row = {'Timestamp': dosing_time, 'Variable': variable, 'Value': value}
    print("New Row:", new_row)  # Check the new row before appending
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv(r"C:/Users/labuser/df.csv", index=False) 
def set_valve_position(channel, position):
    if position == 0:
        #arduino.write(bytes(str(channel) + '0', 'utf-8'))  # Send 'channel1' to Arduino to activate solenoid valve
        #print(f"Solenoid valve on channel {channel} activated")
        arduino.write(f"{channel} {position}\n".encode())
    elif position == 1:
        arduino.write(f"{channel} {position}\n".encode())  # Send 'channel0' to Arduino to deactivate solenoid valve
        #print(f"Solenoid valve on channel {channel} deactivated")
    else:
        print("invalid input")
# Function to read data from input registers (Function Code 4)
async def read_input_registers(modbusclient, start_address, num_elements, slave, datatype):
    response = await modbusclient.read_input_registers(start_address, num_elements, unit=slave)
    if response.isError():
        logging.error(f"Read Input Registers Error for {datatype}: {response}")
    else:
        if datatype == 'B':
            data = response.registers[0]  # Assuming you expect only one register for Unsigned8 datatype
        else:
            data_bytes = b''.join(pack('>H', register) for register in response.registers)
            data = unpack(datatype, data_bytes)
        print(f"{datatype} Data:", data)
    return data
# Function to read holding registers (Function Code 3)
async def read_holding_registers(modbusclient, start_address, num_registers, slave, datatype):
    response = await modbusclient.read_holding_registers(start_address, num_registers, unit=slave)
    if response.isError():
        print("Read Holding Registers Error:", response)
    else:
        if datatype == 'B':
            data = response.registers[0]  # Assuming you expect only one register for Unsigned8 datatype
        else:
            data_bytes = b''.join(pack('>H', register) for register in response.registers)
            data = unpack(datatype, data_bytes)
        print(f"{datatype} Data:", data)
        return data
# Function to write data to holding registers
async def write_holding_registers(modbusclient, start_address, data, slave):
    response = await modbusclient.write_holding_registers(start_address, data, unit=slave)
    if response.isError():
        print("Write Holding Registers Error:", response)
    else:
        print("Write Successful")
# Function to write register
async def write_register(modbusclient, address, value, slave):
    await modbusclient.connect()
    response = await modbusclient.write_register(address, value, unit=slave)
    if response.isError():
        print("Write Single Register Error:", response)
    else:
        print("Write Successful")
# Function to write single holding register (Function Code 6)
async def write_single_register(modbusclient, address, value, slave):
    # Convert the float value to bytes
    byte_value = pack('!f', value)
    # Write the bytes to the specified address
    response = await modbusclient.write_registers(address, [int.from_bytes(byte_value[i:i+2], byteorder='big') for i in range(0, len(byte_value), 2)], unit=slave)
    if response.isError():
        print("Write Single Register Error:", response)
    else:
        print("Write Successful")
async def write_value_bool(client, node_id, value):
    client_node = client.get_node(node_id)
    await client_node.set_data_value(value=value, varianttype=ua.VariantType.Boolean)  # Pass value directly
    #await client_node.set_value(client_node_dv)
    print("Value of : " + str(client_node) + ' : ' + str(value))
async def read_input_value(client, node_id):
   client_node = client.get_node(node_id)
   client_node_value = await client_node.read_value()
   logging.info(f"Value of {client_node}: {client_node_value}")
   return client_node_value
async def write_value_float(client, node_id, value):
    client_node = client.get_node(node_id)
    client_node_dv = await client_node.write_value(ua.Variant(float(value), ua.VariantType.Float))  # Pass value directly
    await client_node.set_value(client_node_dv)
    print("Value of : " + str(client_node) + ' : ' + str(value))
async def keep_connection_alive(modbusclient, client, stop_event):
    """
    Periodically read a register to keep the Modbus connection alive.
    """
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            # Perform a non-blocking read operation to keep the connection alive
            await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 0, 1, 1, 'B')
            await asyncio.sleep(30)  # Send a ping every minute or as needed
            await read_input_value (client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBPumpOnOff")
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions if the connection is lost or any other errors occur
            print(f"Error during connection keep-alive: {e}")
# async def record_dosing_quantity(client, MFC_01DosedQuantity_g, MFC_02DosedQuantity_g):
#     while True:
#         try:
#             await write_value_float(client,"ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.MFC01_DosedQuantity", MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
#         except Exception as e:
#             print(f"Error during write dosed quantity: {e}")
#         try:
#             await write_value_float(client,"ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.MFC02_DosedQuantity", MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
#         except Exception as e:
#             print(f"Error during write dosed quantity: {e}")
 
#Setup one for coupling ()
async def PhosDCI_operations(modbusclient, MFC01_PhosphoramiditeQuantity_g,
                             MFC02_DCIQuantity_g,
                             Phosphoramiditie_VP,
                             DCI_VP,
                             MFC02_CyanethanolQuantity_g,
                             Cyanethanol_VP,
                             MFC02_POSCSOQuantity_g,
                             POSCSO_VP,
                             client
                             ):
   await modbusclient.connect()
   stop_event = asyncio.Event()
   try:
       # Since the Modbus operations are synchronous, run them in executor to avoid blocking the event loop
       loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
       keep_alive_task = asyncio.create_task(keep_connection_alive(modbusclient, client, stop_event))
       ## Phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       # write the code to take Phosphoramidite_VP abd DCI_VP
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, Phosphoramiditie_VP, 1)
       #await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, Phosphoramiditie_VP, 1) #DCI is without manifold for now
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
       # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_01&02
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, write_single_register, modbusclient, 1711, MFC01_PhosphoramiditeQuantity_g/1000, 1) #MFC01_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_single_register(modbusclient,  2711, MFC02_DCIQuantity_g/1000, 1) #MFC02_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient,  1, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient,  0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient,  1, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(12) #20s as test.
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, Phosphoramiditie_VP, 0)
       MFC_01DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f' ) #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC01_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_01DosedQuantity_g)
       MFC_02DosedQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 18, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_DosedQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedQuantity_g)
       #await record_variables()
       #await asyncio.sleep(2)
       #await record_dosing_quantity(client, MFC_01DosedQuantity_g, MFC_02DosedQuantity_g )
       await asyncio.sleep(3600)
        ## Cyanethanol
       # write the code to take Cyanethanol_VP
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, Cyanethanol_VP, 1)
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
       # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_02
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, MFC02_CyanethanolQuantity_g/1000, 1) #MFC01_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
        #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(12) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, Cyanethanol_VP, 0)
       MFC_02DosedCyethanolQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_CyanethanolQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedCyethanolQuantity_g)
       #await record_variables()
       await asyncio.sleep(60)
 
       ## POS_CSO
       # write the code to take PSOCSO_VP
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, POSCSO_VP, 1)
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
        # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_02
       await write_single_register( modbusclient, 1711, MFC02_POSCSOQuantity_g/1000, 1) #MFC02_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register( modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register( modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
        #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(12) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, POSCSO_VP, 0)
       MFC_02DosedCSOQuantity_g = await read_input_registers( modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_POSCSOQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedCSOQuantity_g)
       #await record_variables()
       await asyncio.sleep(3600)
   finally:
       stop_event.set()
       await asyncio.sleep(15) #Disconnect - estimate how long the dosing will take
       await keep_alive_task
       await modbusclient.close()
#Setup one for detrit()
async def Detrit_operations(modbusclient, MFC02_TFAQuantity_g,
                            MFC02_TEMESQuantity_g,
                            TFA_VP,
                            TEMES_VP,
                            client
                            ):
   await modbusclient.connect()
   stop_event = asyncio.Event()
   try:
       # Since the Modbus operations are synchronous, run them in executor to avoid blocking the event loop
       loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
       keep_alive_task = asyncio.create_task(keep_connection_alive(modbusclient,client, stop_event))
       ## Acid detrit
       # write the code to take Phosphoramidite_VP abd DCI_VP
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, TEMES_VP, 1)                        
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
       # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_02
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, MFC02_TEMESQuantity_g/1000, 1) #MFC01_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 256, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Read MFC02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient, 0, 0, 1) #Write MFC01_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(120) #20s as test. Change this to 10mins for actual coupling reaction
       loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, TEMES_VP, 0)
       MFC_02DosedTEMESQuantity_g = await read_input_registers(modbusclient, 8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_TEMESQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedTEMESQuantity_g)
       await asyncio.sleep(1200)
       ## TEMES
       # write the code to take Cyanethanol_VP
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, TFA_VP, 1)    
       await asyncio.sleep(2)
       # Write dosing setpoint to MFC_02
       await write_single_register(modbusclient, 1711, MFC02_TFAQuantity_g/1000, 1) #MFC02_SetpointDosingQuantity
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       # Write MFC01&02_StartBatch
       await write_register(modbusclient,  0, 256, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       #
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       await write_register(modbusclient,  0, 0, 1) #Write MFC02_StartBatch - 256is dose and 0is stop
       # Read MFC01&02_StartBatch
       #Finishing the phosphoramidite + DCI premixing
       await asyncio.sleep(12) #20s as test. Change this to 2mins for actual coupling reaction
       await loop.run_in_executor(None, set_valve_position, TFA_VP, 0)
       MFC_02DosedTFAQuantity_g = read_input_registers(modbusclient,  8, 2, 1, '>f') #Float datatype (big-endian)
       await record_variables('MFC02_TFAQuantity_g', MFC_02DosedTFAQuantity_g)
       await asyncio.sleep(120)
   finally:
       stop_event.set()
       await asyncio.sleep(15) #Disconnect - estimate how long the dosing will take
       await keep_alive_task
       await modbusclient.close()
#Running the dosing sequence
async def main():
   url = "address"
   logging.info(f"Connecting to {url} ...")
   # Modbus TCP client initialization
   modbusclient = AsyncModbusTcpClient('modbusaddress')
   async with Client(url=url) as client:
       await client.connect()
       root = client.get_root_node()
       logging.info(f"Objects root node is: {root}")
       coupling_param = {
                          1.5: (5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 3),
                          2.5: (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
                          3.5: (5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 3)} #PhosDCI_operations(MFC01_PhosphoramiditeQuantity_g, MFC02_DCIQuantity_g, Phosphoramiditie_VP, DCI_VP, MFC02_CyanethanolQuantity_g, Cyanethanol_VP, MFC02_POSCSOQuantity_g, POSCSO_VP)
       detrit_param = {
                         1: (5, 5, 5, 5),
                         2: (5, 5, 5, 5),
                         3: (5, 5, 5, 5),
                         4: (5, 5, 5, 5)}#Detrit_operations(MFC02_TFAQuantity_g, MFC02_TEMESQuantity_g, TFA_VP, TEMES_VP, client):
                         #5: (27.5, 10, 1, 3)}
       while True:
            ## Should replace the node_value woth a 'handshake' value from PLC
            ## One node_value for coupling (potentially sub divided into phos-DCI, quench, PO/PS0)
            ## Onde node_value for detrit (potentially sub divided into traps and then acid)
            node_value = await read_input_value(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing")
            process_stage = await read_input_value(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.ProcessStage") ## Assign Process_stage to GVL.ProcessStage
            if node_value:
                logging.info(f"Node value: {node_value}")
                if process_stage == int(process_stage):
                    #await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing", True)
                    try:
                        await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Detritylation", True)  # Writing an integer value
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error("error")
                    try:
                        await Detrit_operations(modbusclient, *detrit_param[process_stage], client)
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"Error during modbus operations: {e}")    
                    try:
                        await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing", False)  # Writing an integer value
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"Error during write_value_bool dosing 309 operations: {e}")
                    try:
                        await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBDFMode", True)  # Writing an integer value
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"Error during write_value_bool PBDFMode 313 operations: {e}")
                else:
                    try:
                        await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Coupling", True)  # Writing an integer value
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error("error")
                    try:
                        await PhosDCI_operations(modbusclient, *coupling_param[process_stage], client)
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"Error during modbus operations: {e}")    
                    try:    
                        await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.Dosing", False)  # Writing an integer value
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"Error during write_value_bool Dosing 236 operations: {e}")
                    try:
                        await write_value_bool(client, "ns=4;s=|var|C6 S14 PRO.Application.GVL.PBDFMode", True)  # Writing an integer value
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error(f"Error during write_value_bool PBDFMode 330 operations: {e}")
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
            else:
                logging.info("Node value is not True, skipping Modbus operations")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Adjust sleep duration as needed
if __name__ == "__main__":
   asyncio.run(main())
```

Previously the code ran modbus I/O synchronously, had the same issue after 3 hours of operation where I would get a RuntimeError. I changed the modbus I/O to be async but same issue. I'm not super sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect multiple times, remove the `client.connect` line.
Because with `async with Client(url=url) as client` you already connect to the server.

```
 async with Client(url=url) as client:
       await client.connect()   <--- remove this line
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've made this change to the code and its been running smoothly the past 6 hours. I appreciate the help!